# Why isn't ownership preserved with "rsync -a" on my Mac?

Tags: filesystems, rsync

I am copying files from an internal disk to an external one attached by USB (both are formatted as `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`):

```
root# rsync -avi /Volumes/int_hd/ /Volumes/ext_hd/
```

All directories and files on the target drive `/Volumes/ext_hd/` have owner and group `_unknown`. Example:

```
root# ls -ld /Volumes/ext_hd/Users/sam/Documents/
drwx------  16 _unknown  _unknown  544 Mar 28  2014 /Volumes/ext_hd/Users/sam/Documents/
```

Answer (score 12):

If you open the `Disk Utility` app and compare both drives, the internal drive will have **`Owners Enabled`** set to **`Yes`** meanwhile on the external drive it will be set to **`No`**.

[image]

Solution:

Open the `Finder` app, select the external drive, choose `Get Info` from the `File` menu, and **uncheck** the box *ignore ownership on this volume*.

[image]